# Are third-party lenses compatible with Dual Pixel Autofocus (DPAF) on a Canon 80D?

Tags: lens, canon, sigma, tamron

Do third-party lens manufacturers (i.e. Tamron, Sigma) support Dual Pixel Autofocus (DPAF)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming:

- The third party lens is an autofocus lens.
- The third party lens is compatible with the Canon EF mount.
- The third party lens is compatible with the 80D with regards to any type of autofocus. Older third party lenses sometimes have firmware issues that make them less than fully compatible with newer bodies.

From the lens side of things, there's nothing different between using PDAF, using standard contrast detection AF, or using the newer Dual Pixel AF. The camera tells the lens to move the focusing mechanism via the electronic connection between the camera body and the lens. The difference between these various AF methods is in how *the camera* determines which direction and how far it tells the lens to move. If the lens is fully communicating with the camera, it just moves whenever the camera tells it to.

Comment: The third party lens can also be compatible with the EF-S for the 80d.

Comment: 'EF-S' is a subgroup of the EF mount.